# WebKit style for checkbox not working in IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, checkbox

My `checkbox` have a default webkit style like this:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    -webkit-appearance: checkbox;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Now the `checkbox` is not working in **IE8**.
I have tried to overcome this by adding:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<style>
    input[type="checkbox"] {
        font-size: 12px;
        line-height: 1.2em;
        /*-webkit-appearance: none; */
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

this to my **HTML** ,but still it's not working.
As I am not a front end developer ,if there is any thing wrong in the question please feel free to edit.

Note:From the comments i got to this question I understood that webkit styles won't work for IE.So I think i need to find a way to just show default check box style with out Webkit for IE.Any one have any thoughts?

Comment: "*WebKit style for checkbox not working in IE 8*" ... uh, no, of course it isn't. Webkit styles only work on Webkit browsers. IE is not a webkit browser.

Comment: @Spudley please check my latest update in the question

Comment: Re your update: The default checkbox should "just work"... what is it about it that isn't working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Styles the begin with `-webkit-` will only work on browsers that use the Webkit rendering engine.

IE does not use Webkit, and thus it does not support anything that starts with the `-webkit-` prefix.

The whole point of the prefix system in CSS is to tell us that the prefixed styles are non-standard and/or experimental. They will only work in one specific browser engine.

In many (but not all) cases, where there is a `-webkit-` style, this are also equivalent `-moz-` and `-ms-` styles for Firefox and IE. There may also be some browsers that support the style without a prefix. Therefore, when using a prefixed style, you should always check for browser support and whether you need to also specify other alternative syntax.

But even then, they'll only work if you're using a version of the browser that supports it. IE8 in particular is a very old browser, and lacks support for a lot of more modern browser features.

You should not be surprised if modern techniques don't work in IE8. There are work-arounds and 'polyfill' scripts for some features, but others are simply out of reach for this browser.

If you need to support IE8, you need to make sure that any features you're using are going to work, and if they're not, you need to either accept that and give IE8 users a reasonable fall-back solution (so the site is still usable), or find a work-around or alternative.

A good site to visit to find out whether any given feature works across various browsers is [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/).

Answer (score 1):

It's because ie is not based on webkit, but chrome and safari are. For your checkbox, theres css tricks with :before and :after pseudo class.

Take a look here for details http://csscheckbox.com/